# Jekyll on Github pages not serving JSON file

Tags: json, jekyll, github-pages

I made a LeafletJS map that uses a JSON file to create markers. While my script is able to load the JSON on my local machine when I run `jekyll serve`, the site compiled by Github Pages throws a 404 error when it tries to load the JSON. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I guess you have a `baseurl` problem but you'll have to more precise. Like giving a repository url.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out - I had a trailing slash after the filename (`restaurants.json/`) in my AJAX call. While it worked fine in jekyll serve, it didn't work on Github Pages. Ick.